# How to check a pandas.Dataframe for duplicate columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, duplicates

I have to deal with data that is part-raw, part-extracted. I suspect these two columns to be duplicates. In SQL, I can do something like

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table where col1 != col2
```

But how do I do something like the above in Python for `pandas.Dataframe`? More specifically, how do I compare two columns of a csv file and/or a `Dataframe` object, and then see the values or rows which match or fail my criteria for comparison.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just trying to remove rows that contain the same value across two columns you can use the syntax `df[df.col1 == df.col2]` or `df[(df.col1 == df.col2) & (df.col1 == 'some_value') & ...]` for multiple conditions.

If you want to compare across all rows use `df.drop_duplicates()`

If you are trying to compare entire columns then use `df['col1'].equals(df['col2'])`

Answer (score 1):

For this sample dataframe:

```
   Val1  Val2  Val3
0     1     2     3
1     1     1     3
2     3     2     1
3     2     2     2
4     1     2     3
5     2     2     2
6     1     1     3
```

You can locate rows where `Val1` column value equals `Val2` column value:

```
df[df['Val1']==df['Val2']]
```

Yields:

```
   Val1  Val2  Val3
1     1     1     3
3     2     2     2
5     2     2     2
6     1     1     3
```

Or if you want `!=`:

```
df[df['Val1']!=df['Val2']]
```

Yields:

```
   Val1  Val2  Val3
0     1     2     3
2     3     2     1
4     1     2     3
```